# Word wrap in gedit

Tags: word-wrap, gedit

I am using gedit & I have a very huge line and I am not able to see that complete line because gedit gets stucking.
so, I wanted to do word wrapping in gedit.
I searched but I didnt found word wrap option in gedit.

How I can do wrapping in gedit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check Gedit preferences, or else you can use [TextWrap](http://hartmann-it-design.de/gedit/TextWrap/)

Comment: Preferences -> Tab. View -> Text Wrapping -> Enable text wrapping -> check

Answer (score 8):

In the gedit Text Editor menu click **Edit**, and then click **Preferences**. A popup named gedit Preferences opens up. In the same popup on the first Tab named View, under the sub-heading Text Wrapping click the check box named **Enable text wrapping**, to toggle the text wrap feature on or off.

These steps have been tested for gedit 3.10.4 version running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5):

Check in the status menu in the lower bottom corner of the Gedit window.

[image: screenshotgedit]

If you want to do it in a as per-file basis, you can use modelines https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-modelines.html.en.

For example have a comment in the first line of your text file.
In this case, `autowrap:nil` will suppress text wrapping.

```
// -*-indent-tabs-mode:t;c-basic-offset:4;tab-width:4;autowrap:nil;-*-
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu 22.04:**

1. Open Preferences by Clicking on the hamburger menu on the top-right.
2. Click on the View tab
3. Under the Text wrapping section >> Check 'Enable text wrapping' >> Uncheck 'Do not split words over two lines'.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most complete list of Gedit plugins I know of can be found at [wiki.gnome.org](https://wiki.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins). It includes a.o. the `Text Wrap` plugin.

> [To install it,] you need to download the files and put them
>   in your ~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/ directory (which may need to be
>   created). They need to be in that exact directory; subdirectories are
>   not scanned for plugins. [copied from that page]